# How to fetch both record 1 week past date and sum of total

Tags: php, codeigniter

my model:fetch data from db in codeigniter one week data and sum of total_sale.

```
public function get_data() 
{
    $this->db->select_sum('total_sale');       
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("-1 week"));
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d 59:59:59");
    $this->db->where("store_date >= '" . $start_date . "' AND store_date <= '" . $end_date . "'");
    $query = $this->db->get('one_month_report');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple query:

```
public function get_data() {
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("-1 week"));
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59");


    $sql = "select sum(total_sale) from one_month_report where store_date >= '" . $start_date . "' AND store_date <= '" . $end_date . "'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Also $end_date will be `date("Y-m-d 23:59:59");`

Answer (score 0):

Add This line of code

```
 $query = $this->db->select('*');
 $query = $this->db->select_sum('total_sale', 'sum_total_sales');
```

before

```
 $this->db->where("store_date >= '" . $start_date . "' AND store_date <= '" . $end_date . "'");
```

And you are done.

Comment: total_sale is column name

Answer (score 0):

try this where condition should be something like this

```
$this->db->where("store_date >=", $start_date);
$this->db->where("store_date <=",$end_date );
```